# how to send empty GET request body in angular

Tags: angular, get, httpclient

I want to send raw json empty body with GET request in Angular. I mean the body should be this: {} and I want to send this data as RAW JSON in GET request. can you help me with this please?

I've tried to use XHR and FETCH, but none of them worked.

Comment: you can't send a body (empty or not) in a get request.